# Redirecting All Requests - Linksys Router

Tags: router, wireless-router, redirection, url

I currently have a Cisco WRV200 Wireless-G VPN router with RangeBooster, with that I've created an Access Point and set up a small Local Area Network.

This Local Area Network obviously has no access to the Internet, however I want to re-purpose the network.

Is there a way I can direct any URL a person visits while on the network to a local HTML file?

I've heard about the DD-WRT solutions, but apparently DD-WRT doesn't have installation support for my router. Is there a simpler way of doing this? Do I install new firmware on it? If so, what firmware?